# jQuery wrapAll select options in optgroup causes change of value

Tags: jquery

With a simple `select`:

```
<select>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<button>Click to wrap</button>
```

and using jQuery to `wrapAll` options in an `optgroup`:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("option").wrapAll('<optgroup label="My Group"></optgroup>');
});
```

this results in the selected value changing to the last option.

https://jsfiddle.net/333jx9aq/

At least it does in Firefox and Chrome. It works 'properly' in IE. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this could be considered a jQuery bug.

The way that `wrapAll` works is as follows:

1. Insert the new wrapper (`<optgroup>` in this case) in the parent before the first element to be wrapped.
2. Create a document fragment object.
3. Append each of the elements being wrapped to the document fragment. This removes them as children of the original parent (the `<select>`)
4. Append the document fragment to the new wrapper.

The value of a `<select>` always has to be one of its `<option>`s, so long as it has any options. When step 3 removes the selected option, its value is set to be the first remaining option. Since it removes each of the options in order, at the end of that loop the value is the last option.

Then when the document fragment is appended, nothing resets the value of the `<select>` back to its old value, so it's still set to the last of the original options.

You can work around this by saving the value yourself.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var oldValue = $("select").val();
  $("option").wrapAll('<optgroup label="My Group"></optgroup>');
  $("select").val(oldValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<button>Click to wrap</button>
```